# Google OAuth 2 redirect_uri_mismatch - OmniAuth Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0, google-api, omniauth

I've a problem with authenticating Google account with my Rails app.
I'm using [omniauth-google-oauth2 gem](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) with Devise.
Always get this Error when I try to access google account:

```
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback did not match a registered redirect URI
```

I'm sure that the registered redirect URI in my google console app is right and identical with requested one, just like that:

[image]

so what's main the problem here?

Comment: how are you setting the redirect uri in the code? are you sure that screenshot is from the correct project and client id?

Comment: yeah, i'm sure. and i don't set the redirect uri in the code manually, devise and omniauth do it automatically for me and the reidrect_url param is right!

Comment: I copy and pasted my redirect_uri error directly into my google api redirect_uri console, and realized I was redirecting to 127.0.0.1 as opposed to localhost, so make sure you are careful with such small details.

Answer (score 12):

try this way :

```
add require "omniauth-google-oauth2" to devise.rb in config/initializers folder
```

`add http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback` into Redirect URL in google API console https://console.developers.google.com

restart server

Comment: but I have to add `gem 'omniauth-oauth2', '~> 1.3.1'` as well along with  `"omniauth-google-oauth2"` and before `bundle install` I need to do `bundle update omniauth-oauth2`

Answer (score 3):

Mine solution is to force redirect_url in both (code/token) stages, devise.rb initializer:

```
CALLBACK_URL = 'https://SOMESERVER/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback'

Devise.setup do |config|
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2,
    "SOMECLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "SOMEKEY",
    {
    :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => 'C:\Ruby21\cacert.pem'}},
    :provider_ignores_state => true,
    :prompt => "select_account",
    :redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL,
    setup: (lambda do |env|
      request = Rack::Request.new(env)
      env['omniauth.strategy'].options['token_params'] = {:redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL}
    end)
    }
end
```

there is discussion about the issue here: https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/181

Answer (score 0):

Be careful of what client id you are setting.
Google API provides two: 
Client ID for Google Compute and App Engine
Client ID for web applications

You need to use Client ID for web applications

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you set up the Product Name and Email address via the Consent Screen Link.

Per the omniauth-google-oauth2 documentation you need to:

Go to 'https://console.developers.google.com'
Select your project.
Click 'APIs & auth'
Make sure "Contacts API" and "Google+ API" are on.
Go to Consent Screen, and provide a 'PRODUCT NAME'
Wait 10 minutes for changes to take effect.

I had the same issue, made the updates, waited 10 minutes, still nothing, went to lunch, then it started to work. Guess patience was part of the key to success on this one.