# Google+ OAuth on Rails = redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

I use rails 4.2.5, tryed `omniauth-gplus` and `omniauth-google-oauth2` lastest versions gems and got the same issue

```
omniauth.error"=>#<OAuth2::Error: redirect_uri_mismatch: 
{ "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch" }>,  
"omniauth.error.type"=>:invalid_credentials,
"omniauth.error.strategy"=>#<OmniAuth::Strategies::GPlus>
```

In `OmniauthCallbacksController` I am getting in to `:failure`

(`OAuth` works good with other providers)

I already added `require "omniauth-google-oauth2"` in `device.rb` like in [Google OAuth 2 redirect_uri_mismatch - OmniAuth Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515244/google-oauth-2-redirect-uri-mismatch-omniauth-rails-app)

Actually I`m trying with same settings.

I think failure is in my console.developers.google.com settings.
Now I do not know what else combination of Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs to try.
(I tried it with and without last '/', on localhost, localhost alias(with and without port) or heroku)

Can you say me, what settings are exactly right for google+ api for http://localhost:3000?

Or maybe I`v missed out something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

Personally, when I work with oauth redirects I like to use thin

```
$ gem install 'thin'

$ thin start --ssl
```

Then I set the redirect uri to

```
https://127.0.0.1:3000
```

This way, there won't be a protocol mismatch and will let you keep the session alive between the requests

Comment: Thank you. The gem wasn`t good. Thin help`s find it
Right gem for mail.ru accounts is `omniauth-mail_ru`